# Configuring Playwright using runsettings

Tags: c#, playwright, playwright-dotnet

When inheriting PageTest class, `IBrowser` is already configured using runsettings.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 : PageTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task HomepageHasPlaywrightInTitleAndGetStartedLinkLinkingtoTheIntroPage()
    {
        await Page.GotoAsync("https://playwright.dev");

        // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
        await Expect(Page).ToHaveTitleAsync(new Regex("Playwright"));

        // create a locator
        var getStarted = Page.Locator("text=Get Started");

        // Expect an attribute "to be strictly equal" to the value.
        await Expect(getStarted).ToHaveAttributeAsync("href", "/docs/intro");

        // Click the get started link.
        await getStarted.ClickAsync();

        // Expects the URL to contain intro.
        await Expect(Page).ToHaveURLAsync(new Regex(".*intro"));
    }
}
```

What if I wanted to instantiate IBrowser manually like this and use runsettings to set browser to be firefox?

```
<RunSettings>
  <Playwright>
    <BrowserName>chromium</BrowserName>
    <LaunchOptions>
      <Headless>false</Headless>
      <Channel>msedge</Channel>
    </LaunchOptions>
  </Playwright>
</RunSettings>
```

```
var playwright = Playwright.CreateAsync().Result;
_browser = playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync().Result;
```

It would explictly use Chromium, instead of whats required by runsettings.

For my use case, I tried to use Playwright-provided IBrowser, but due to some things that I need to do within AssemblyInitialize methods, I'd better have the solution of creating IBrowser manually.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not totally clear, but in case you need the runsettings file to be picked up by Visual Studio when you execute your tests, then here is a possible solution.

From the Visual Studio menu,

1. Select "Test"
2. Choose "Configure Run Settings."
3. Select "Select Solution Wide runsettings File."
4. Choose your runsettings file (e.g., Headless.runsettings).

Here is a file that uses firefox, set the headed mode.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <!-- Playwright Settings-->
> <RunSettings>
> <Playwright>
> <BrowserName>firefox</BrowserName>
> <LaunchOptions>
> <Headless>false</Headless>
> </LaunchOptions>
> </Playwright>
> </RunSettings>
> ```

[Configure the runsettings file to be picked up by Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qbvQ.png)

Comment: He wanted to override the settings via code. Instead of picking from runsettings we should have a way to override runsettings and decide from code at runtime which browser we want. anyway to call any override function just like we have BrowserNewContextOptions